# RoR ActiveRecords Conditions - How to access data in my tables correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, database, activerecord

New day, new error I guess.

I have a "comments" table. If I print out @comments=Comment.all, I get the data from my database in this format:

```
[#<Comment id: 1, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-10 18:11:44", updated_at: "2014-01-10 18:11:44", content: "yolo drake", receiver: nil>, #<Comment id: 2, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-10 18:12:20", updated_at: "2014-01-10 18:12:20", content: "yolo drake", receiver: nil>, #<Comment id: 3, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-10 18:14:07", updated_at: "2014-01-10 18:14:07", content: "schallulaaa udddaa", receiver: "Linda Lamar">, #<Comment id: 4, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-10 18:17:28", updated_at: "2014-01-10 18:17:28", content: "noch ein versuch", receiver: nil>, #<Comment id: 5, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-10 18:18:42", updated_at: "2014-01-10 18:18:42", content: "scdcsvcdf", receiver: nil>, #<Comment id: 6, commentable_id: nil, commentable_type: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-01-10 18:20:05", updated_at: "2014-01-10 18:20:05", content: "luiscdncdij", receiver: "Miriam Hagen">]
```

I want to get all the comments where "receiver" = aSpecificName AND where "commentable_type" = offer.

BUT

1) If I do @comments.each do in order to get each comment, instead of each Comment-database object it gives me this for all comments:

```
#<Comment:0x007f9ec4cbb488> #<Comment:0x007f9ec4cba9c0> #<Comment:0x007f9ec4cb97a0> #<Comment:0x007f9ec4cc2710> #<Comment:0x007f9ec4cc0d48> #<Comment:0x007f9ec4ccbf90> # (the list goes on same style)
```

2) If I do something like

```
@offerpm = Comment.where({ receiver: @user["first_name"], commentable_type: "offer" }),
```

it gives me this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9ec4dd3c80>
```

===> What is going on here and how do I select what I want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Comment.where(receiver: 'aSpecificName', commentable_type: 'Offer')
```

EDIT:

I see you pretty much answered your own question too! The Relation object is an array-like object which you can also use the `each` method on:

```
Comment.where({ receiver: @user["first_name"], commentable_type: "offer" }).each do |comment|
  # do stuff here
end
```

Be sure to read the [documentation on the ActiveRecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Still gives me the same. Any idea where those numbers like '0x007f9ec4dd3c80' come from and what they mean?

Comment: It's the output of the `to_s` method on the Relation object. The Relation is part of ActiveRecord's query builder. Try calling `to_a` or `each` on it. Do read the documentation I linked to. It answers all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you are seeing are the object. You are already selecting what you want to select, i.e. the correct object. Now you just need to call the method to see the fields you want instead of those numbers.

So in your example to get to the receiver use,

```
@offerpm.receiver
```

or `@offerpm.commentable_type` to see that field.

Hope that helps.